# The number that can be write in 1 ways and 2 ways of a triangular number subtract another a triangular number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

I get this question while I am thinking about the number system that is defined in the same way of prime number but isn't prime number.

This is how I start defining my number. At first, I create infinite list of sets. Let set

\begin{align}
S_1 &= \{x|x_1=1,x_2=2x_1+1,x_{n+1}=2x_n-x_{n-1}+1,n\in I,n≥2\} = \{1,1+2,1+2+3,1+2+3+4,...\} = \{1,3,6,10,...\} \\
S_2 &= \{x|x_1=2,x_2=2x_1+1,x_{n+1}=2x_n-x_{n-1}+1,n\in I,n≥2\} = \{2,2+3,2+3+4,2+3+4+5,...\} = \{2,5,9,14,...\} \\
S_3 &= \{x|x_1=3,x_2=2x_1+1,x_{n+1}=2x_n-x_{n-1}+1,n\in I,n≥2\} = \{3,3+4,3+4+5,3+4+5+6,...\} = \{3,7,12,18,...\} \\
&... \\
S_k &= \{x|x_1=k,x_2=2x_1+1,x_{n+1}=2x_n-x_{n-1}+1,n\in I,n≥2\} = \{k,2k+1,3k+3,4k+6,...\}\\
&... \\
\end{align}

Let number $A_1$ is the number that is member of only 1 sets and $A_2$ is the number that is member of only 2 sets.

In my intention, $A_1$ is analogus to the number 1 and $A_2$ is analogous to prime number.

Then I realize that

- $S_1$ is the set of triangular number except the $T_0$ or 0.
- $S_2$ is the set of $T_n-T_1$ when T is triangular number and $n\in I$,n≥2.
- $S_3$ is the set of $T_n-T_2$ when T is triangular number and $n\in I$,n≥3.
- $S_4$ is the set of $T_n-T_3$ when T is triangular number and $n\in I$,n≥4.
- ...
- $S_k$ is the set of $T_n-T_{k-1}$ when T is triangular number and $n\in I$,n≥k.

That mean $A_1$ is the number that can be write in 1 ways of a triangular number subtract another a triangular number.
Let x is member of $A_1$. There is only 1 pair of triangular number $T_a$ and $T_b$ where $x=T_a-T_b$ when $T_a>T_b$.

Also $A_2$ is the number that can be write in 2 ways of a triangular number subtract another a triangular number.

As I try to find some early member of $A_1$ and $A_2$, I have conjectures that

- $A_1 = \{x|x=2^n,n\in I,n≥0\} = \{1,2,4,8,16,...\}$
- $A_2$ = {any prime number that is odd number} = {3,5,7,11,13,...}

I think there must be something relate to the formula of the triangular number but I can't find any reference about a triangular number subtract another a triangular number. Could any one explain me and proof that my conjecture is correct or not ? Or give me any reference about a triangular number subtract another a triangular number ?

Comment: Probably worth observing that $T_a-T_b=\frac12(a-b)(a+b+1)$. I'm pretty sure you can use this to prove the $A_1$ conjecture without too much trouble. I'm more skeptical about the $A_2$ conjecture, but notice that this formula does give a partial factorization of $T_a-T_b$, so if there are counterexamples it could help find them. It also means that there are naive bounds on how big $a$ and $b$ can be, which is nice— a priori it could be that even small numbers could be generated by big triangulars that just happened to cancel properly.

Comment: (For ease of others' reading: I believe that the $I$ in the OP is the set of integers, which is more commonly notated "$\mathbb{Z}$".)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky For the $A_1$ conjecture, I still have no idea how to prove that (a-b) and (a+b+1) can't be in form of $2^n$ in the same time for any integer a and b.

Comment: Note that $a-b$ and $a+b+1$ have opposite parity, but $1$ is the only odd factor of $2^n$. (Also, I think I'm coming around on $A_2$ now, too.)

Comment: @EricNathanStucky Thank you. So, all $2^n$ is $A_1$ but how do you proof that there is no $A_1$ that isn't $2^n$ ?

Comment: Well, see how far you can get just by inverting the logic. If a number is not $2^n$, then it has an odd factor... and try to get at least two $a$ and $b$ that work. For this I suspect the $\frac12$ will be important, otherwise the primes would have shown up in $A_1$ as well.